# Removing all full 0 rows in an 3d matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a large image matrix 125x200x3, the image has many large areas of black so there are many rows of all 0's. I want to remove all these black areas completely. I know that I should be using all(m==0,3) but it seems like I don't quite understand how to use it with 3d matrix.

```
m(all(m==0,3),:,:)=[]
```

exceeds matrix...
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to remove *rows* containing all black, do this:

```
m(all(all(m == 0,3),2),:,:) = [];
```

The inner call to [ALL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/all.html) (what you were doing) will give you a 125-by-200 logical matrix with ones for every black pixel. The outer call to [ALL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/all.html) operates across dimension 2 (the columns), giving you a logical vector with ones for rows that contain all black. This is what you then use as your index to remove rows.